# Controlling what clicks trigger jQuery lightGallery

Tags: jquery, html, href, lightgallery

Have been trying to implement the jQuery LightGallery onto my website, but I have a unique structure for how the thumbnails need to be. These galleries are for photos taken at a specific events with only one person viewing the gallery. I have my own javascript based 'LIKE' system for these photos so people can LIKE the photos. Problem has been people want to look at the images on their phones, and the gallery wasn't built for that. LightGallery was the answer. So underneath each thumbnail I have a LIKE button that's a DIV with a link on it that fires a javascript function. Problem is, when I try to implement this in the LIST structure of LightGallery, the LightGallery listener overrides the link on that DIV, instead firing the large image. So for example...

```
<li data-src="<?=$FrameLink?>" id='Cell<?=$FrameNumber?>'>

<a href="#" title="IMAGE #<?=$FrameNumber?>"><img src="<?=$ThumbLink?>" height="173" width="117" border="0" id='IMG<?=$FrameNumber?>' class="IMGThumb"></a>

<a href="javascript:loadintoIframe('FavList','favlist.php?Name=<?=$Name?>&Do=Remove&Frame=<?=$FrameWOExt?>=')" onclick="FavChange('<?=$FrameNumber?>','ON')"><div id='NoLike<?=$FrameNumber?>' class='NoLike'></div></a>

 </li>
```

So as you can imagine, the last link and div should allow you to click on it and trigger the loadintoiframe javascript... but the LightGallery overrides that link. I've tried to z-index through CSS to see if I can get that DIV above whatever LightGallery was doing, but everytime I try to click on that div it just enlarges the photo.

So my question is how can I change the LightGallery code to ONLY add the link that triggers the image enlarging to JUST the image, and not the entire list item? Or perhaps to have it just listen for a click on the thumbnail rather than the entire list item? Thanks!

Here's a photo to illustrate my point...
[Photo of how I'd like it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opd9K.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. I know it's not ideal to modify the plugin's original code but that's what I did - a very minor change. I've got to links for my image - one to download the image and the other to zoom the image and show in the lightgallery popup.

If you open up `lightgallery.js` then go to **line 176** I changed it from:

```
_this.$items.on('click.lgcustom', function(event) {
```

to

```
_this.$items.find('a.zoom').on('click.lgcustom', function(event) {
```

as the class name on the link I want to use to show the popup is called `zoom`. You could also extend the plugin's options to write this as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited and added the UL version, but I think this might be a bit tedious

```
 $('ul').click(function(event){
  //check whether the anchor tag is the 'LIKE'  
  if (event.target.id.indexOf('NoLike')!=-1)
  {  
     //Using JQuery to trigger the click event of the anchor tag
     //First I get the parent of the div, which is the anchor tag
     var par=$(event.target).parent();
     //Then I bind the href event of the parent anchor tag to another anchor
     var $a=$('<a></a>');
     $a.attr('href',par.attr('href'));
     //This anchor tag $a appends to the body where it is out of the 
     //LightGallery's listeners
     //$('body').append($a);  
     //I commented the above append code, as you donot require it,
     $a.get(0).click();
     //$a.remove(); Remove is not required since not appending to body
     return false;
  }
  return true;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I like where you're going, but there's two problems with that... the ID for the 'NoLike' div is actually different on each image. For example, if the image is 0001.jpg, the ID for the NoLike DIV is NoLike0001. That allows me to change the background image of the div to display LIKE instead of LIKED. Since this can vary on each gallery because of the random image file names, I can't expect there to always be a NoLike0001 div.

Comment: Second, I went into the main LightGallery javascript file and hunted around, but it doesn't appear it actually is looking for the `<li>` list html at all, it's using the initial `<ul id="light-gallery" class="gallery">` by the id and then looking at the children being clicked.

Comment: I have edited the code, I guess this should work for your div irrespective of the ids changing

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it with 3 functions. On element clicks which you don't want to show the gallery just call *preventGalleryShow* on others call *showGallery*.

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var hideGallery = function(){
    $('.lg-backdrop').addClass('hidden');
    $('.lg-outer').addClass('hidden');
};

var showGallery = function(){
    $('.lg-backdrop').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.lg-outer').removeClass('hidden');
};

var preventGalleryShow = function(event, $galleryObj){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $galleryObj.off('onAfterOpen.lg').on('onAfterOpen.lg',function(e){
        hideGallery();
    });
    $galleryObj.trigger('onAfterOpen.lg');
};
```

EXAMPLE:

```
$('.command-delete', function(event){
    preventGalleryShow(event,$gallery);
    //do your magic
});

$('.anythingelse').on('click', function(event){
    showGallery();
});
```